# Pulling date data with onclick var

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to setup a send to email on click with app maker, one of my objects that sends is the date. I have this code for pulling that data:

```
var todayDate = widget.parent.parent.descendants.Field.value
```

I then get this error when testing the date data entries:

> Failed due to illegal value in property: 4
>   at (unknown)
>   at (unknown)
>   at Inbound_Call.Container.Form1.Form1Header.Form1Spinner.visible:-1:132
>   at (unknown)
>   at (unknown)
>   at (unknown)
>   at Inbound_Call.Container.Form1.Form1Footer.Form1SubmitButton.onClick:7:40

Comment: Based on experience, the data type you are passing to the script you have on the submit button `Form1SubmitButton.onClick:7:40` is not a date data type; That is why you are getting "ilegal value".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to make server call to send an email, smth like this:

```js
google.script.run.myServerFunction(myDate, otherParam1, otherParam2);
```

I can suggest that call fails due to [App Script parameters constraints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#detailed-documentation):

> Legal parameters are JavaScript primitives like a Number, Boolean, String, or null, as well as JavaScript objects and arrays that are composed of primitives, objects, and arrays. A form element within the page is also legal as a parameter, but it must be the function’s only parameter. **Requests fail if you attempt to pass a Date**, Function, DOM element besides a form, or other prohibited type, including prohibited types inside objects or arrays. Objects that create circular references will also fail, and undefined fields within arrays become null....